# What is the difference between router.navigate and router.parent.navigate in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

Actually I want to know the difference between `router.navigate(['User'])` and `router.parent.navigate(['User'])`. In my Angular2 project act same things for both.

thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

You try to navigate to the route defined in the current router (`router.navigate(['User'])` or to a one defined in the parent router (`router.parent.navigate(['User'])`).

As a matter of fact, you can define several levels of routes. If the `User` route is defined in the route config associated with the router, `router.navigate(['User'])` will work. If it's in the route config associated with the parent router, `router.parent.navigate(['User'])` will work.

For example, if you have two levels and want to navigate to the root level, you can use this:

```
router.navigate(['/User']);
```

**Example**

- In the `AppComponent` component (application component):

  ```
  @RouteConfig([
    {
      path: '/sub/...',
      name: 'SubComponent',
      component: SubComponent,
      useAsDefault: true
    },
    {path: '/user', name: 'User', component: UserComponent}
    {path: '/other', name: 'Other', component: OtherComponent}
  ])
  ```
- In the `SubComponent` component:

  ```
  @RouteConfig([
    {path: '/test',   name: 'Test',     component: TestComponent}
  ])
  ```

In this case, `router.parent.navigate(['User'])` will work for components defined in routes of the `SubComponent` component (for example: `TestComponent`). `router.navigate(['User'])` will work for components defined in routes of the `AppComponent` component (for example: `OtherComponent`).

Comment: what will be happen if I use `router.navigate(['User'])` instead of `router.parent.navigate(['User'])`  for `TestComponent`?